# regex to validate apple bundle identifier or apple id

Tags: javascript, php, ios

I am working on an API and I need to match Apple bundle identifier or Apple App ID with regex in Javascript and PHP, for the Javascript I noticed all Apple mobile apps identifiers starts with id then a set of numbers e.g **id1234567** this what I have done but however it is not working, trying to match this **id1234567** or any number pattern that starts with id

```
var ios_prop = "id1234567";
regexp =  /id\[0-9]+/;
if (regexp.test(ios_prop))
{
alert ("This is a valid Apple ID");
} else {
alert ("Invalid Apple ID");
}
```

but it tells me "Invalid Apple ID".

For the PHP I have no idea on how to get that done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `\` from your regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the string starts with `"id"`, use the `^` anchor.
To specify the group of digits, you can use `[0-9]` or `\d`.

Your regular expression, `/id\[0-9]+/` is escaping the first `[` special character. You're looking for `"id["` which does not match.

Use `regexp = /^id[0-9]+/;` or `/^id\d+/`